# NLog not writing to file after explict reload of configuration

Tags: c#, nlog

It's basically a copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047143/nlog-not-creating-log-files-configuration-through-code), I know, but even after following the other post and the troubleshooting guide I'm still stuck.

It's a .net standard 2.0 library using NLog 4.7.10, without configuration file, doing the following:

```
internal Log()
{
    NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
    NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
    NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = "nlog-internal.txt";

    LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
    LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;

    this.Core = this.CustomLog("core");
    this.Core.Info("Done!");
}

public Logger CustomLog(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

    if (LogManager.Configuration.FindRuleByName(name) == null)
    {
        FileTarget target = new FileTarget(name)
        {
            FileName = string.Format("{0}.txt", name),
            Layout = DefaultLayout,
            AutoFlush = true,
            DeleteOldFileOnStartup = true
        };

        LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(target);
        LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, target, name);
        LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
    }

    return LogManager.GetLogger(name);
}
```

Everything is then imported in a net core 3.1 application

**What I get:** the nlog-internal.txt is written, the console displays the same information

```
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6727 Debug --- NLog configuration dump ---
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6727 Debug Targets:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6727 Debug Rules:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6727 Debug --- End of NLog configuration dump ---
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6924 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.6924 Info Validating config: Targets=0, ConfigItems=0
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7186 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7602 Debug Found assembly location directory: 'D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1' (NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c)
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7602 Debug Auto loading based on NLog-Assembly found location: D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7602 Debug Search for auto loading files in location: D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Debug Found assembly location directory: 'D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1' (BrokenGalaxy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Debug Auto loading based on GetEntryAssembly-Assembly found location: D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Debug Auto loading based on AppDomain-BaseDirectory found location: D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Debug Start auto loading, location: D:\Work\netcoreapp3.1
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Debug Auto loading done
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7694 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7849 Trace Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7849 Debug Setting 'NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers.UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper.uppercase' to 'true'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7849 Trace Wrapping NLog.LayoutRenderers.LevelLayoutRenderer with NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers.UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7849 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7849 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace  Scanning Property Inner 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}' NLog.Layouts
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace   Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.7978 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Debug Setting 'NLog.LayoutRenderers.DateLayoutRenderer.format' to 'HH:mm:ss.fff'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace Scanning DateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${date}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8196 Debug Registered target core: NLog.Targets.FileTarget
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Targets for core by level:
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Trace => core
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Debug => core
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Info => core
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Warn => core
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Error => core
2021-07-01 13:09:28.8362 Debug Fatal => core
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9517 Info AppDomain Shutting down. Logger closing...
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9592 Trace Flushing all 1 targets...
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9592 Trace ForEachItemInParallel() 1 items
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9592 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9592 Trace Parallel task completed. 0 items remaining
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9694 Debug Flush completed
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9694 Debug Targets not configured for logger: core
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9694 Debug Closing logging configuration...
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9694 Debug Finished closing logging configuration.
2021-07-01 13:09:30.9694 Info Logger has been shut down.
```

**What I expect:** to also have a core.txt file with a "Done!" line inside it. I also tried using "${{basedir}}{0}.txt" in the FileName' string format, but to no avail.

There are no errors, nor execptions. In addition if I try to configure NLog via configuration file it works, so I'd rule out permission issues as well.

Maybe it's that *Debug Targets not configured for logger: core* near the end of the log file, but I have done the same in other projects and it was working..

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method you are looking for:

```
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

It will refresh all existing Logger-objects, so they will recognize the change you have made to the LoggingRules.

You should NOT use this method, since it doesn't do what you expect:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

It only does something useful if you have loaded configuration from `NLog.config`-file using `XmlLoggingConfiguration`. Where it will re-read the entire configuration from file again, and return the result (But will not apply it). The `Reload()`-method should have been protected, and not have been part of the public API (Since it is a source of confusion).

Comment: Thanks, that was it! So this means that in the other project where I said it was working, it was because I also had a config file present. Didn't know about ReconfigExistingLoggers.